# Adjusting white space

Tags: margins, koma-script

I got a template I'm using for my report. Now I have printed it in A4 and think the is to much white space on all 4 sides of the paper. Reading the settings, I can't see where this is set. Anyone that know how I can change the white space?

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier} % Use the Adobe Utopia font for the document
\usepackage[english, swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{changepage} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{sectsty} % Allows customizing section commands
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Custom headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancyplain} % Makes all pages in the document conform to the custom headers and footers
\fancyhead{} % No page header - if you want one, create it in the same way as the footers below
\fancyfoot[L]{} % Empty left footer
\fancyfoot[C]{} % Empty center footer
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage} % Page numbering for right footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove header underlines
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove footer underlines
\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt} % Customize the height of the header

\numberwithin{equation}{section} % Number equations within sections (i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4)
\numberwithin{figure}{section} % Number figures within sections (i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4)
\numberwithin{table}{section} % Number tables within sections (i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4)

\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Removes all indentation from paragraphs - comment this line for an assignment with lots of text

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\horrule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}} % Create horizontal rule command with 1 argument of height

\title{ 
\normalfont \normalsize 
\textsc{University} \\ [25pt]
\horrule{2pt} \\[0.4cm] % Thin top horizontal rule
\huge Title\\ % The assignment title
\horrule{2pt} \\[0.5cm] % Thick bottom horizontal rule
}
\author{Author \\ E-mail: mail}
\date{\normalsize\today} % Today's date or a custom date
\graphicspath {{figures/}}
\begin{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enlarge `DIV`. Example:

```
\documentclass[...,DIV=10]{scrartcl}
```

Then the margins are smaller but with the same ratio. The default value for `fontsize=10pt` and `paper=a4` is `DIV=8`.

[image]

But you will get a warning by the KOMA-Script package `typearea`:

> ```
> Package typearea Warning: Bad type area settings!
> (typearea)                The detected line width is about 17%
> (typearea)                larger than the heuristically detected line width.
> (typearea)                You should e.g. decrease DIV, increase fontsize
> (typearea)                or change papersize.
> ```

There are too many characters in a text line. Note that it is not recommended to use line lengths with more than 60 to 70 characters. See the [KOMA-Script documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) section "2.1. Fundamentals of Page Layout" for more information.

---

BTW do not load package `caption` twice and do not use package `sectsty` together with a KOMA-Script class. These classes have their own possibilities to customize the layout of section titles. `headheight` can be set as a class option. It is not a good idea to set `\parindent` to `0pt` while not using a parskip. Maybe you want to add the `parskip` option instead?

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=10pt,
  DIV=10,
  headheight=13.6pt,
  %parskip=half-% instead of setting \parindent to 0pt
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier} % Use the Adobe Utopia font for the document
\usepackage[english, swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{changepage} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

\usepackage{tikz}% loads also graphicx and xcolor
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\numberwithin{table}{section}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}% <- maybe you want to use class option parskip?

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\horrule}[1]{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{#1}} % Create horizontal rule command with 1 argument of height

\title{ 
\normalfont \normalsize 
\textsc{University} \\ [25pt]
\horrule{2pt} \\[0.4cm] % Thin top horizontal rule
\huge Title\\ % The assignment title
\horrule{2pt} \\[0.5cm] % Thick bottom horizontal rule
}
\author{Author \\ E-mail: mail}

\date{\normalsize\today} % Today's date or a custom date
\graphicspath {{figures/}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\selectlanguage{english}% blindtext does not have a swedish version
\blinddocument
\Blindtext[15]
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: DIV=10 it is as it is quickest but probably not the prettiest.

Comment: This is technically correct, but such long lines at 10pt and single space will be a pain to read. I urge the OP to read the introduction of the "memoir" class (`texdoc memoir`) about relations between line lenght, font size, margins, and readability...

Answer (score 4):

You can reduce the white space of the page by setting the offsets in preamble. For e.g.

```
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
```